# Rails Controller/Devise see empty parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I've created a form for a user to sign up for my app with a minor tweak by adding the ability to also include their company name.  However, my rspec tests and through manual testing it appears that the parameters are not being passed to create the user/company.

In the end, I need to be able to create a `user` and also create a `company` with just the name of the company for now.

Here's a visual of the signup form:

[image: sign up form]

> RegistrationsController:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :sign_up_params

  def new
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    self.resource.company = Company.new
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  protected

  def sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user|
      user.permit(:email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, company_attributes: [:name])
    end
  end
end
```

> Model Company.rb

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :domain, :stripe_id
  validates_presence_of :name
  has_many :users
  has_many :devices
  has_one :subscription

end
```

> Model User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :lockable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_presence_of :email, :name
  belongs_to :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
end
```

> My registration form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

   <%= f.fields_for :company do |company_form| %>
       <%= company_form.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', autofocus: true, placeholder: 'ACME Inc.' %>
   <% end %>

   <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'John Doe' %>

   <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'john.doe@company.com' %>

   <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', autocomplete: 'off', placeholder: 'Password' %>

   <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control', autocomplete: 'off', placeholder: 'Password Confirmation' %>

   <%= f.submit 'Sign up', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat' %>

<% end %>
```

> My feature test (which is currently failing):

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "User Registration", :type => :feature do
  scenario "A new user is created" do
    # this will cover the user profile signup info
    visit "/users/sign_up"
    fill_in "user_company_attributes_name", with: "ACME Inc."
    fill_in "user_name", with: "Bob Jones"
    fill_in "user_email", with: "bob@jones.com"
    fill_in "user_password", with: "password"
    fill_in "user_password_confirmation", with: "password"
    click_button "Sign up"
    expect(page).to have_text("You have signed up successfully")
  end
end
```

> The feature test results:

```
Failures:

  1) User Registration A new user is created
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_text("You have signed up successfully")
       expected to find text "You have signed up successfully" in "x 4 errors prohibited this user from being saved: Email can't be blankPassword can't be blankName can't be blankCompany must exist NeoUI Sign up to start getting secure can't be blank can't be blank can't be blank"
     # ./spec/features/user_registration_spec.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

> And just to confirm it I attempted to add a user by hand:

```
website_1   | [9493b284-c9dc-4832-9be9-e876feb621f4] Started POST "/users" for 172.19.0.1 at 2017-06-29 11:37:30 +0000
website_1   | [9493b284-c9dc-4832-9be9-e876feb621f4] Cannot render console from 172.19.0.1! Allowed networks: 172.23.0.0/172.23.0.255, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
website_1   | [9493b284-c9dc-4832-9be9-e876feb621f4] Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
website_1   | [9493b284-c9dc-4832-9be9-e876feb621f4]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"HiqRhDZ4hddR65vZ+EVPP3dezr3yemz5HuU0gy4Wo/Tt7xtpm00F8JG6kNdMjPWQiGrPOu9xk0FfF1HjtFaqiQ==", "user"=>{"company_attributes"=>{"name"=>"Test Company"}, "name"=>"Test User", "email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
website_1   | [9493b284-c9dc-4832-9be9-e876feb621f4]    (3.2ms)  BEGIN
website_1   | [9493b284-c9dc-4832-9be9-e876feb621f4]   User Exists (1.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", ""], ["LIMIT", 1]]
website_1   | [9493b284-c9dc-4832-9be9-e876feb621f4]    (2.0ms)  ROLLBACK
website_1   | [9493b284-c9dc-4832-9be9-e876feb621f4]   Rendering /usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.3.0views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/signup
website_1   | [9493b284-c9dc-4832-9be9-e876feb621f4]   Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.3.0views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb (4.1ms) [cache miss]
website_1   | [9493b284-c9dc-4832-9be9-e876feb621f4]   Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.3.0views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/signup (35.3ms)
website_1   | [9493b284-c9dc-4832-9be9-e876feb621f4] Completed 200 OK in 814ms (Views: 705.5ms | ActiveRecord: 7.1ms)
```

I've look at various posts on the web trying to figure this out and assume it's something related to my nested `company` attribute in the user form, but still can't solve this mystery.

Comment: The error in the log says you have a user already existed with that email. Try different email and check

Comment: @Pavan I think that's a devise std error message to rollback.  The user is created by the email address and there is no email being passed for some reason.  The actual HTML output I see when attempting manually is more relevant in the feature test.

Comment: @Pavan In that query he is selecting the users with email equal to blank string `WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", ""],` while in the HTTP post request to `/users` he actually has in the parameters `user[:email] = test@test.com` so I would like to see the controller action 

As this is devise I don't think you did change that create action, maybe you should debug that create action to understand what is wrong with the request..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think devise registration controller create action is not using the strong params and is not getting that input.

They show up in the request

```
"user"=>{"company_attributes"=>{"name"=>"Test Company"}, "name"=>"Test User", "email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

but they are probably not allowed as strong params, in fact if you read your query it is done with `email = ""` a blank string. No parameters are getting sanitized.

```
WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", ""], ["LIMIT", 1]]
website_1   | [9493b284-c9dc-4832-9be9-e876feb621f4]    (2.0ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Maybe your sanitize method is wrongly written? Maybe you could try like this, even including him in the Application Controller...

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email, :name, company_attributes: [:name]])
end
```

Also with Devise I do not include the `:password` in my strong params, I read that it is not safe, but right now I am not sure. Still as my understanding standard Devise works already with `:password` and `:password_confirmation`, but as you are creating a new action, you may need all the parameters...

Also it may be that the new action is using your strong params in your controller, but the create action that is from this controller is still using their own strong params

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

Comment: So you essentially believe that I'm dealing with this because the `keys:` are missing?  I'll give the `configure_permitted_parameters` this small change when I get back to the office.

Comment: As a note, it doesn't look like you can change the method name that devise uses.  I originally had `sign_up_params` but as soon as I changed this back to the devise default as was suggested, it worked!

Comment: @Godzilla74 Great ! Yes, it is not very easy. Devise is complex. I am glad this helped you. Thanks